# Building footprints of Atlantic city, NJ

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, footprint

does anyone know where to get information of building footprints information on Atlantic city?

Comment: The first place I would check for footprint information is the city and then county GIS departments if they exist. Sometimes you can find it on their website, sometime you need to call the department to find out if it exists (may not be advertised) and if you can get a copy (and for how much). Failing that, OSM and other crowd-sourced data, perhaps area universities, might be places to look.

Answer (score 1):

Three options off the top of my head:
Checkout openstreetmap.org and use OSM data, or
Post this question at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/, or
Digitize the footprints from Google Maps (or Bing Maps).